Inserting HTML into random positions within a paragraph tag
I'm trying to insert a random length span into random places within a paragraph tag using jQuery. Think "REDACTED" text within a document.
Here's what I've done so far:


$(document).ready(function() {
  var xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (14 - 4 + 1) + 4);
  for (var i = 0; i < xx; i++) {
    var $newsp = $('<span class="blackout">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>');
    $("p").append($newsp);
  }
});
body {
  font: normal normal 400 14pt/1.15em 'Courier New', monospace;
}

.blackout {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #000;
}

.ins {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ins">
  <p>To forgive is to set a prisoner free and discover that the prisoner was you. You gain strength, courage and confidence by every experience in which you really stop to look fear in the face. You must do the thing which you think you cannot do.</p>
  <p>The unexamined life is not worth living. You gain strength, courage and confidence by every experience in which you really stop to look fear in the face. You must do the thing which you think you cannot do.</p>
  <p>Nothing is a waste of time if you use the experience wisely. A man who won't die for something is not fit to live.</p>
</div>




You should have paid more attention to the message you got when you tried to post the fiddle link as a link.

Please see Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Additionally, you forgot the part where you describe the problem you're observing and ask about that problem.  Where specifically are you stuck?  What specifically isn't working as expected?

As a guess, what you may be looking to do is: (1) Read the text from the target element into a string; (2) Split the string at a random (or near-random based on your own logic) point in its length; (3) Add each part of the split text into its own <span>; (4) Insert your generated "redacted" <span> wherever you like in this new array of <span> elements; (5) Empty the target element and append your <span> elements to it.

Here's a solution.


$(document).ready(function() {
  // Function to generate a random number
  function random(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  $(".ins p").each(function() {
    var paragraph = $(this).text();
    var words = paragraph.split(" ");
    var newContent = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      // Randomly decide whether to redact this word
      if (Math.random() < 0.3) { // 30% chance to redact
        var blackoutLength = random(3, words[i].length);
        var blackedOutText = "<span class='blackout'>" + "&nbsp;".repeat(blackoutLength) + "</span>";
        newContent += blackedOutText + " ";
      } else {
        newContent += words[i] + " ";
      }
    }

    // Set the new content with redacted words
    $(this).html(newContent.trim());
  });
});
body {
  font: normal normal 400 14pt/1.15em 'Courier New', monospace;
}

.blackout {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #000;
}

.ins {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ins">
  <p>To forgive is to set a prisoner free and discover that the prisoner was you. You gain strength, courage and confidence by every experience in which you really stop to look fear in the face. You must do the thing which you think you cannot do.</p>
  <p>The unexamined life is not worth living. You gain strength, courage and confidence by every experience in which you really stop to look fear in the face. You must do the thing which you think you cannot do.</p>
  <p>Nothing is a waste of time if you use the experience wisely. A man who won't die for something is not fit to live.</p>
</div>



Thanks to @david for the idea.
The script starts by splitting each paragraph's text into an array of words using the split(" ") method.
A loop iterates through each word, and a random decision is made (with a 30% chance) whether to redact the word. If it's chosen to be redacted, a <span> element with a random length of spaces is added in place of the word.
After processing all words, the new content (which includes redacted words) is set as the HTML of the original paragraph using $(this).html(newContent.trim()).

I created a jQuery plugin below that will redact words by looking for non-zero-length text nodes.
If it encounters one of these, it will:

Extract the words
Remove the node
Append to the parent

A word or
Redacted span (25% chance)



I avoided calling innerHTML and $.fn.html, and instead worked with the DOM.
Note: I kept the text in the span for debugging purposes.
Here it is in action:


$(function() {
  $('.ins').redactWords(); // Call the plugin on the entire container
});

/* jQuery plugin: $.fn.redact */
(function($) {
  $.fn.redactWords = function() {
    redactRecursive(this);
    return this;
  };

  function redactRecursive($el) {
    $el.each(function() {
      $(this).contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && this.textContent.trim()) {
          const parent = $(this).parent();  // Get the parent element
          const words = this.textContent.trim().split(/\s+/);
          $(this).remove();  // Remove the original text node
          
          words.forEach((word, index) => {
            const chance = Math.random();
            if (chance < 0.25) {
              $('<span>')
                .addClass('redacted')
                .css({ width: `${word.length}ch` })
                .text(word) /* Keep for DEBUG */
                .appendTo(parent);
            } else {
              parent.append(document.createTextNode(word)); // Append text node to parent
            }

            // Append a space after the word unless it's the last one
            if (index < words.length - 1) {
              parent.append(document.createTextNode(' '));
            }
          });
        } else if (this.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          redactRecursive($(this));
        }
      });
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
body {
  font: normal normal 400 14pt/1.15em 'Courier New', monospace;
}

.redacted {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1rem;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: yellow; /* Keep for DEBUG */
}

.ins {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ins">
  <p>To forgive is to set a prisoner free and discover that the prisoner was you. You gain strength, courage and confidence by every experience in which you really stop to look fear in the face. You must do the thing which you think you cannot do.</p>
  <p>The unexamined life is not worth living. You gain strength, courage and confidence by every experience in which you really stop to look fear in the face. You must do the thing which you think you cannot do.</p>
  <p>Nothing is a waste of time if you use the experience wisely. A man who won't die for something is not fit to live.</p>
</div>



